# Does iconv_mime_encode acknowledge already set encodings?

Tags: php, encoding

I have trouble getting iconv_mime_encode to use already set encodings.

```
iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'utf-8');
iconv_set_encoding('input_encoding',    'utf-8');
iconv_set_encoding('output_encoding',   'iso-8859-1');

$string = "hétérogène";

$a_prefs = array(
    'scheme' =>         'Q',
    'line-length' =>    500);

echo iconv_mime_encode('Subject', $string, $a_prefs);

-> Subject: =?utf-8?Q?h=C3=A9t=C3=A9rog=C3=A8ne?=
```

The result is utf8 when I wanted iso-8859-1.

```
$a_prefs = array(
    'scheme' =>             'Q',
    'line-length' =>        500,
    'output-encoding' =>    'iso-8859-1');

echo iconv_mime_encode('Subject', $string, $a_prefs);

-> Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?h=E9t=E9rog=E8ne?=
```

Here the result is ok, but I thought I shouldn't have to set output-encoding explicitly.
Am I wrong, or is it a php bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks very wrong, [but it's documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-encode.php): If you don't set the `output-encoding` in the `preferences` array, it falls back to  `iconv.internal_encoding`, instead of `iconv.output_encoding`.

[Looking through the `iconv` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.iconv.php), it appears that they all use the internal coding as fallback value; not a single one appears to use the output encoding.

By the way, as of PHP 5.6 all of the `iconv.*_encoding` settings [are deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/iconv.configuration.php), the `default_charset` setting will be used as default instead.

Answer (score 1):

As you can [read in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-encode.php), the default for the output charset in `iconv_mime_encode` is `iconv.internal_encoding`, not `iconv.output_encoding`.

> output-charset    string   Specifies the character set to use to compose the MIME header.     iconv.internal_encoding     UTF-8

**BTW**: all 3 of the settings are [*deprecated* in PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/iconv.configuration.php#ini.iconv.output-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

I could have read the documentation once more, I still would have misread the part where the default output encoding is based on internal.

Thank you.